# Proof question: If $4 \not \mid a^2$, then $a$ is odd.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Would somebody mind checking this proof? I'm not entirely confident in it, but I can't think of another way to approach it. Specifically, I'm not sure if the portion I bolded actually proves the statement true.

Proof:

Let $a$ be an integer. We will prove the contrapositive statement , "if a is even, then $4 \mid a^2$." By definition of even, $a=2k$. Substituting, we get $4 \mid (2k)^2$. We compute:

$4 \mid (2k)^2$

$4 \mid 4k^2$

$4 \mid 2(2k^2)$.

Now, let $j=2k^2$. Therefore, $4 \mid 2j$. Then, by definition of division, **$2=4a$**. Hence, $4 \mid a^2$, as desired. QED

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to write if $4 \not\mid a^2$, then $a$ is odd?  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Yes. Is there a way to write special symbols on here? Edit: Nevermind, thanks for the link!

Comment: You’ve proven that $a=1/2$.  That’s not possible.

Comment: Should I have factored out a 4 instead of a 2?

Comment: If $a = 2k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $a^2 = 4k^2 \implies 4 \mid a^2$.

Comment: $a^2=4k^2 \Rightarrow 4|a^2$ so once you reach that point, you're done.

Comment: After the line $4\, | \,4k^{2}$ there is nothing else to be done.

Comment: Ah, took it too far. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is okay up until the last few lines.

So you have shown so far that $4|4k^2$ -- this is sufficient to prove your result, you don't have to take it any further!

How do we know this holds and gives the desired result? If $a|b$, then $\exists n \in \Bbb Z$ such that $b = an$. Here, $b = 4k^2, a = 4$. There thus exists an integer $n$ such that $4k^2 = 4n$. That very integer is $k^2$. Since $a^2=4k^2$ for some $k$, then $4|a^2$, concluding the proof.

Comment: Got it, thanks!